# Move MainWindow from an other Page/Class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my MainWindow.xaml I have a rectangle. Whenever the user holds down the left mousebutton above the rectangle, he can move the window. This is needed since I am using the property WindowStyle="None".

Now to my question. How can move the window from an other page/class?

I´ve already tried to add an object reference of MainWindow to the page but that just ends up in a StackOverflowException.

```
MainWindow M_W = new MainWindow();
```

And the LeftMouseButtonDown Event for the rectangle:

```
private void Window_Move_Login(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       M_W.DragMove();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to instantiate another MainWindow instance. Use the existing instance instead.

```
private void Window_Move_Login(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       Application.Current.MainWindow.DragMove();
    }
```